# Avoid meteor framework to override cordova config.xml and AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: cordova, meteor

I am building an android application using meteor framework. I am making changes for **activity** and **intent**.

My changes in **AndroidManifest.xml** and cordova **config.xml** gets overridden on every fresh build due to which my development has stopped.

How can I avoid meteor to override these files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a special top-level folder called cordova-build-override. The whole file tree of this directory will be cp -R (copied overwriting existing files) to the Meteor project right before the build and compilation step.

For example: if you want to have a customized config.xml, you can put it in project/cordova-build-override/config.xml.

Its described in [https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration#advanced-build-customization](http://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration#advanced-build-customization) .

Comment: This does not work for us at all.  We've tried any number of combinations, but anything we place in cordova-build-override is simply ignored.  See https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/5840#issuecomment-186184372

This is an extremely blocking issue.  Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: Its been almost an year now and worked at that time. 
Maybe new version of meteor ignores cordova-build-override.
It was a workaround never an official answer.

Comment: You could find your way by creating a specific plugin for that based on this https://github.com/dagatsoin/cordova-multidex